# Issues with queryset and slicing

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 2 models, `Company` and `Product`, with `Product` having a ForeignKey to `Company`

```
class Product(Meta):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, 
        related_name='products', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

I do the following filtering:

```
 company = Company.objects.filter(account=account, pk=company_pk)
        if not company:
            raise Http404
        product = Product.objects.filter(company=company, pk=product_pk)
        if not product:
            raise Http404
        return product
```

And I have the following error:

```
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.
```

`company_pk` and `product_pk` are just variables.  If I remove the Product filter there is no error.

I presume it happens because company result is a QuerySet and is pushed as argument in `Product.objects.filter`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Company is a queryset. You might want to do

```
Product.objects.filter(company=company[0], pk=product_pk)
```

Or better yet you can use the relations in the ORM to simplify into 1 lookup.

```
Product.objects.get(company__account=account, company__pk=company_pk, pk=product_pk)
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't use [0] because I thought is  just one result, but I presume is a list with one element

Comment: `filter` returns a queryset, which is sliceable like a sequence. `get` is fine if you're sure that the pk exists, if it doesn't it'll throw an exception which you can catch and turn into a 404. Or if you're in a view, as it appears you are, you can use the `get_object_or_404` shortcut: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404

Comment: @kevswanberg - This Q&A was very difficult to find via a search.  Would you consider expanding your answer to a generic example (such as:  `qs = Model1.objects.filter( attribute__in=Model2.objects.filter(##))` converted into your correct answer).  As @TyrannoTaiwo and you both note, the error is thrown due to using a queryset within a queryset.  But the error suggests `slice` as  a problem - and searching around slices yields a lot of `slicing a queryset` type Q&A  (making this specific use case issue difficult to find).

Answer (score 19):

As said in the accepted answer, company is a queryset.

> The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

Instead of this

```
product = Product.objects.filter(company=company, pk=product_pk)
```

try this

```
product = Product.objects.filter(company__in=company, pk=product_pk)
```

`__in` can handle querysets larger than one (multiple records of a table).

This can be found in the django Many-to_one relationships section of the documentation.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Django documentation can be scary for a beginner like me because of its length and depth, though it provides solutions to most issues if you can crack it.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be created when you pass a `queryset` for the value you are searching with.

```python
Company.objects.filter(account=account, pk=company_pk)
```

actually  returns a `queryset` and that `queryset` can't be used in this query

```python
Product.objects.filter(company=company, pk=product_pk)
```

without producing the error message.

What is really missing here is a `.get`, either like

```python
Company.objects.filter(account=account, pk=company_pk).get()
```

or

```python
Company.objects.get(account=account, pk=company_pk)
```

Comment: Doesn't .get() return an error if there are multiple objects that fit?